# Popup view sliding from the bottom has a gap on non X devices

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an `UIView` that slides from the bottom. The view has a leading, trailing and bottom to superview with value 0 and height 220.

I have two outlets to height and bottom constraint.

```
func hidePicker() {
   pickerBottomConstraint.constant = -heightConstraint.constant
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in

    })
}

func showPicker(date: Date?) {
    pickerBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in

    })
}
```

This works how intended on XS, XS Max, XR devices, but when I run on other devices, like for example iPhone 6, there is always a gap (24 size) at the bottom:

This is when is hidden - you can see the top of view:

[image]

This is when is revealed - there is a gap at the bottom:

[image]

The view contains a date picker a stack view and a view, they all have bottom constraints set to 0.

So why do I have that gap at the bottom ? I tried all day figuring out why, but can't seem to understand.

PS: I tried a simple project to reproduce this, and I can't. It works in a simple project, apparently there is something just with my project, but maybe someones has an idea on where to look next.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your project or at least the relevant parts of your project?

Comment: I am not sure if I can, it is too big, not sure how to show storyboards and code alltogheter

Comment: Well then it's hard to figure out what's going wrong. Maybe you can share the whole project via dropbox or something similar? As you said... in a demo project I set up everything works as expected.